# Angular 2 Dynamic Forms: How to create dependent dropdown

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am creating dynamic form by referring to [Angular 2 Dynamic Forms](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html)

Everything works good. but the problem I am facing is creating dependent drop-down. eg: I want to create form where user can select there address using `Country`, `City`, `State` drop-down.

```
new DropdownField({
  key: 'country',
  label: 'Country',
  options: [
    {key: 'usa',  value: 'USA'},
    {key: 'uk',  value: 'UK'}
  ],
  order: 4
}),

new DropdownField({
  key: 'state',
  label: 'State',
  options: [
    {key: 'taxas',  value: 'taxas'},
    {key: 'detroit',  value: 'detroit'}
  ],
  order: 5
}),

new DropdownField({
  key: 'city',
  label: 'City',
  options: [
    {key: 'houston',  value: 'Houston'},
    {key: 'austin',  value: 'Austin'}
  ],
  order: 5
})
```

Edit: Following is the template.

```
<div class="form-group" [formGroup]="form">
  <label [attr.for]="field.key" class="control-label">{{field.label}}</label>
  <div [ngSwitch]="field.controlType">
    <input *ngSwitchCase="'textbox'"
      formControlName="{{field.key}}"
      [id]="field.key"
      [type]="field.type"
      class="form-control"
      [placeholder]="field.placeholder"
      [readonly]="field.readonly"
    >
    <select [id]="field.key" *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'" formControlName="{{field.key}}" class="form-control">
      <option style="display:none" value="">Choose an option</option>
      <option *ngFor="let opt of field.options" [value]="opt.key">{{opt.value}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div style="color: red;" *ngIf="!isValid">({{field.label}} is required)</div>
</div>
```

What I want is when user select `Country`, list of `State` should get populated and when user select `State`, list of `City` should get populated but all using Dynamic Forms.

Comment: and the `DropdownField` here is ... ? I don't actually see where you are using the reactive forms here

Comment: You can refer Angular 2 Dynamic Forms example link provided in question.

Comment: I already searched for `DropdownField` there and I find nothing. Please clarify your question and post what you've tried

Comment: Ohh, You can search for `DropdownQuestion`.

Comment: Could you include your template code please?

Comment: @Shamsher it does not work like that. I **will not** search for anything. If you want to receive some help, please be nice to others and add the necessary information to your question.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a Plunkr which demonstrates dependent drop-downs: https://plnkr.co/edit/b5FKSp06XMfQul5pYQti?p=preview

It has a first drop-down list to select a *product type* (small or large) which updates a second drop-down list showing *only the small or the large products*. You could easily translate this example to dependent drop-downs for country/state/city.

The Plunkr shows two techniques to generate the values for the dependent drop-down:

- **Recalculating the values on every `change` event** emitted by the first drop-down.
- **Applying a custom pipe** to the values of the dependent drop-down so that they are automatically bound to & filtered by the value of the first drop-down.

Comment: One question: 
'productsAfterChangeEvent = [];
  productForm: ControlGroup;'
Where is ControlGroup declared? I've changed it to "FormGroup" and it worked. This is the type returned in constructor at fb.group. Thanks!

Comment: No idea. It's probably a typo, it should be `FormGroup.` ;)

Answer (score 0):

With mew versions of Angular, you can simply use `valuechanges` method on reactive form and subscribe to changes:

```
this.myyForm.controls['productCategory'].valueChanges.subscribe(change => {
  console.log(change);

  if (change === 'THIS') {
    this.myOtherControls = ['Enabled']
  } else {
    this.myOtherControls = ['Enabled', 'Disabled']
  }
});
```