# Angular 4 Dynamic Forms: Dependent Dropdown

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, dynamic, angular-forms

I am creating a dynamic form based on [Angular 4 Dynamic Forms](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form) .

Everything is working out great! However, I have run into an issue with the dropdown. I would like to have a dependent dropdown. When the user selects a value in the dropdown it will display checkboxes, based on an attribute - possibly `name`.

**service**

```
  new DropdownInput({
    key: 'dropdown',
    label: 'Dropdown Testing',
    options: [
      {key: 'example1',  value: 'Example 1'},
      {key: 'example2',  value: 'Example 2'}
    ],
    order: 1
  }),

  new CheckboxInput({
    key: 'checkbox1',
    label: 'checkbox1 - example1',
    name: 'example1',
    order: 2
  }),

  new CheckboxInput({
    key: 'checkbox2',
    label: 'checkbox2 - example1',
    name: 'example1',
    order: 3
  }),

  new CheckboxInput({
    key: 'checkbox3',
    label: 'checkbox3 - example2',
    name: 'example2',
    order: 4
  }),

  new CheckboxInput({
    key: 'checkbox4',
    label: 'checkbox4 - example2',
    name: 'example2',
    order: 5
  })
```

**html**

```
<!-- CHECKBOX -->

<div class="col-xs-12" *ngSwitchCase="'checkbox'">

  <input class="form-check-input"
         type="checkbox"
         [formControlName]="input.key"
         [id]="input.key"
         [name]="input.name">

  <label class="control-label"
         [attr.for]="input.key">{{input.label}}</label>
  <a class="info-tooltip"><i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

  <span class="help-block"
        *ngIf="!isValid">{{inputError}}</span>

</div>

<!-- DROPDOWN -->

<div class="col-xs-12" *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'">

  <label class="control-label"
         [attr.for]="input.key">{{input.label}}</label>
  <a class="info-tooltip"><i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

  <span class="help-block"
        *ngIf="!isValid">{{inputError}}</span>

  <select [id]="input.key"
          [formControlName]="input.key">
    <option *ngFor="let opt of input.options"
            [value]="opt.key">{{opt.value}}</option>
  </select>

</div>
```

So in this example if a user were to click on Example 1 - I would only like to display checkboxes 1 & 2. Is this possible? Should I be formatting the data differently?

*Note 1: I have found the link on how to go from a dependent dropdown to another dropdown ([Angular 2 Dynamic Forms: How to create dependent dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42501988/angular-2-dynamic-forms-how-to-create-dependent-dropdown?rq=1)
), but do not know how to effectively use it with checkboxes.*

*Note 2: The reason I have my checkbox separate from textbox (not shown) is how they are displayed visually in the app. I know I could combine them for less/more efficient code.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would add one option called `showWhen` to base model:

**base.model.ts**

```
export class BaseModel<T> {
  value: T;
  key: string;
  label: string;
  required: boolean;
  order: number;
  controlType: string;
  showWhen: ControlCondition; <===================== new option

  constructor(options: {
    value?: T,
    key?: string,
    label?: string,
    required?: boolean,
    order?: number,
    controlType?: string,
    showWhen?: ControlCondition
  } = {}) {
    this.value = options.value;
    this.key = options.key || '';
    this.label = options.label || '';
    this.required = !!options.required;
    this.showWhen = options.showWhen;
    this.order = options.order === undefined ? 1 : options.order;
    this.controlType = options.controlType || '';
  }
}

export class ControlCondition {
  key: string;
  value: string;
}
```

As you can see it takes `key` and `value`. Depending on these values we can decide whether to show control or not.

Now you can describe condition for showing your controls like:

```
new DropdownInput({
  key: 'dropdown',
  label: 'Dropdown Testing',
  options: [
    { key: 'example1', value: 'Example 1' },
    { key: 'example2', value: 'Example 2' }
  ],
  order: 1
}),

new CheckboxInput({
  key: 'checkbox1',
  label: 'checkbox1 - example1',
  showWhen: {
    key: 'dropdown',   // if control with key `dropdown` has value `example 1` then show
    value: 'example1',
  },
  order: 2
}),
```

Now go to the component that is called `DynamicFormQuestionComponent` in angular tutorial. In my example I called it `DynamicFormComponent`. Here we need to add logic for showing/hidding control:

**dynamic-form.component.ts**

```
export class DynamicFormComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() input: BaseModel<any>;
  @Input() form: FormGroup;

  control: FormControl;

  hidden: boolean;

  subscription: Subscription;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.control = this.form.get(this.input.key) as FormControl;
    this.setUpConditions();
  }

  setUpConditions() {
    if (!this.input.showWhen) {
      return;
    }

    let relatedControl = this.form.get(this.input.showWhen.key);
    if (!relatedControl) {
      return;
    }

    this.updateHidden();
    this.subscription = relatedControl.valueChanges.subscribe(x => this.updateHidden());
  }

  updateHidden(): void {
    let relatedControl = this.form.get(this.input.showWhen.key);
    this.hidden = relatedControl.value !== this.input.showWhen.value;

    this.hidden ? this.control.disable() : this.control.enable();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.subscription) {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

and last thing you need to do is to add `*ngIf="!hidden"` in template

[**Ng-run Example**](https://ng-run.com/edit/D2AiLy1m3uiZtkUyqMPg?open=app%2Fdynamic-form%2Fdynamic-form.component.ts&layout=1)

Comment: Thanks! I have a rather odd request. But when I send the data to the server I need to have the data from all the checkboxes sending. For example, let’s say the user has clicked on example 2 in the dropdown and clicked on checkbox 3 only (and not checked, then unchecked). The data reads: `dropdown: example2, checkbox3: true`, but I would like for the data to read: `dropdown: example2, checkbox1: false, checkbox2: false, checkbox3: true, checkbox4: false`. Is that possible?

Comment: There is a line `this.hidden ? this.control.disable() : this.control.enable();` that is reponsible for that. You can also read getRawValue from formGroup. I've update example

Comment: You can also call `reset` method value if `this.hidden` is `true`